# References sorted as cited, styles except unsrt

Tags: citing

I know the unsrt style sorts references as cited. I am looking for a style that does the same, but which differentiates the author‘s name in print from titles. Any differentiation is ok: boldface, capitalisation, quotation marks... As I am citing newspaper titles, which begin with names, I think it would aid clarity.

Comment: Please give an example of what, according to you, would "differentiate the author‘s name in print from titles". E.g., are you looking to create a line break between the authors' names and the title of the publication?

Comment: @Mico anything. Bold print, capitalisation, quotation mark... I just don’t want to write Trump. And then people think it’s the author;)

Comment: So you're looking for a bibliography style which (a) doesn't sort the entries alphabetically by authors' surnames, (b) creates numeric-style citation call-outs (that's what `unsrt` does, after all), and (c) employs some extra methods in order to create a visual distinction between the contents of the formatted `author` field on the one hand and the remaining formatted material on the other. Is this basically correct? If not, please clarify further what it is you wish to achieve.

Comment: @Mico The author doesn’t need to be distinct from all the rest, but at least from the adjacent string.